# .htaccess Redirect Rule for platform change

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I recently moved a site from vanilla PHP to the WordPress CMS platform. One thing that changed was the URL format of posts.

The old URL format was `/news-and-views/{id}/{slug}` like this:

https://newable.co.uk/news-and-views/840433571/award-winning-exporters.php

This actual URL was https://newable.co.uk/news-and-views/article.php?Id=840433571&title=award-winning-exporters

I used this rewrite rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(news-and-views)/([0-9]+)/([^/]+).php /$1/article.php?Id=$2&title=$3 [L]
```

The new URL format is /{slug} like this:

https://newable.co.uk/award-winning-exporters/

So I wrote a new rule like this:

`RewriteRule ^(news-and-views)/([0-9]+)/([^/]+).php /$3 [L]`

I also tested it.

[image]

However, clicking an article through Twitter still takes me to the following URL:

https://newable.co.uk/news-views/840433571/award-winning-exporters.php

Here is the full list of Redirections

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# Turn on Rewrite Engine
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(news-and-views)/([0-9]+)/([^/]+).php /$3 [L]

# Lending redirects
Redirect 301 /lending/ https://newable.co.uk/money/business-loans
Redirect 301 /lending/business-finance/ https://newable.co.uk/money/business-loans
Redirect 301 /lending/business-finance/product-details.php https://newable.co.uk/money/business-loans
Redirect 301 /lending/business-finance/how-it-works.php https://newable.co.uk/money/business-loans
Redirect 301 /lending/business-finance/introducers.php https://lending.newable.com/register
Redirect 301 /lending/business-finance/mentoring.php https://newable.co.uk/money/business-loans

# Private Investing redirects
Redirect 301 /private-investing/ https://newable.co.uk/money/eis-investment
Redirect 301 /private-investing/entrepreneurs/ https://newable.co.uk/money/eis-investment
Redirect 301 /private-investing/entrepreneurs/apply-for-funding.php https://newable.co.uk/money/eis-investment
Redirect 301 /private-investing/partners.php https://newable.co.uk/money/eis-investment
Redirect 301 /private-investing/about-us.php https://newable.co.uk/money/eis-investment
Redirect 301 /private-investing/press/ https://newable.co.uk/money/eis-investment
Redirect 301 /private-investing/events/ https://events.newable.co.uk/

# International Trade redirects
Redirect 301 /international-trade/ https://newable.co.uk/advice/supporting-exporters
Redirect 301 /international-trade/export-engine.php https://newable.co.uk/advice/supporting-exporters
Redirect 301 /international-trade/department-for-international-trade.php https://newable.co.uk/advice/supporting-exporters
Redirect 301 /international-trade/erdf.php https://newable.co.uk/advice/supporting-exporters

# Business Advice redirects
Redirect 301 /business-advice/ https://newable.co.uk/advice
Redirect 301 /business-advice/growth-services.php https://newable.co.uk/advice/innovation
Redirect 301 /business-advice/social-impact-programmes.php https://newable.co.uk/advice/social-impact
Redirect 301 /business-advice/ready-to-supply.php https://newable.co.uk/advice/social-impact
Redirect 301 /business-advice/events.php https://events.newable.co.uk
Redirect 301 /business-advice/support.php https://newable.co.uk/advice/social-impact
Redirect 301 /business-advice/partners.php https://newable.co.uk/advice
Redirect 301 /business-advice/erdf-projects/global-growth.php https://newable.co.uk/advice/supporting-exporters
Redirect 301 /business-advice/erdf-projects/casts.php https://newable.co.uk/advice
Redirect 301 /business-advice/get-exporting-kent-and-east-sussex.php https://newable.co.uk/advice
Redirect 301 /business-advice/erdf-projects/asean.php https://newable.co.uk/advice
Redirect 301 /business-advice/erdf-projects/south-east-international-business-growth.php https://newable.co.uk/advice

# Space redirects
Redirect 301 /space.php https://newable.co.uk/space

# Property redirect
Redirect 301 /property.php https://newable.co.uk/space

# Digital redirect
Redirect 301 /digital.php https://newable.co.uk

# America Made Easy
Redirect 301 /AmericaMadeEasy https://newable.co.uk/advice/america-made-easy/

# Generic redirects
Redirect 301 /faqs.php https://newable.co.uk/faq
Redirect 301 /team.php https://newable.co.uk/team
Redirect 301 /locations.php https://newable.co.uk/locations
Redirect 301 /reports https://newable.co.uk/downloads
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Did you add this as a new rule now, or did it replace the existing one? Please show the full rule set.

Comment: Sorry, posting now

Comment: You are only rewriting internally here, if you want the URL shown in the address bar to change, then you need to issue an external redirect. Make the flag part of the rule `[R=301,L]` - `R` for redirect, `301` for status code Moved Permanently.

Comment: See, that would make more sense...

Comment: For some reason that caused an internal server error.

Comment: Check the error log to find out what the cause is.

Comment: I've realised none of my 301s will actually work, as they include the rest of the path, which I don't want...

Comment: Yes, the `Redirect` directive does prefix matching. If you don’t want that effect, you need to do this using RewriteRules as well.

Comment: Oh... I'm have a stupid moment, so Redirect is just going to the URL and add the extra. Given that, should I just change every use of Redirect to a Rewrite? As I don't want any of the old URL to follow over

Comment: I would probably not do all of that in .htaccess, but use a plugin like https://wordpress.org/plugins/safe-redirect-manager/

Comment: Is it possible you could just edit the permalinks settings to what you want?